# Using getattrs() to access Foregin Key values

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using a basic form in Django to collect a users choices which will be used to create a filter of objects and then output to csv.  I would like to use the values from the form to access data in the different models.

My form looks like this..

```
class CustomReportForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES=[('Asset Labels','Asset Labels'),
             ('Asset List','Asset List')]

    REPORT_FIELDS = [('id','ID'),
                     ('name','Name'),
                     ('location','Location'),
                     ('status','Status'),
                     ]

    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    col_choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=REPORT_FIELDS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(AssetLocation.objects.all(), required=False)
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(AssetStatus.objects.all(), required=False)
```

I have 2 models included in the form 'AssetLocation' and 'AssetStatus'.

```
class AssetLocation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.company) + " - " + self.location


class AssetStatus(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.company) + " - " + self.status
```

I also have an Asset model

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(AssetLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(AssetStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.company) + " - " + self.name
```

And I have a view which accesses the POST data and tries to use that to get data.

```
def AssetList(request):
    assets = Asset.objects.all()

    cols = request.POST.getlist('col_choices')

    for a in assets:
        data = []
        for i in cols:
            data.append(getattr(a,i))

        print(data)
```

This works as expected.  I am getting the location and status of each asset but its returning the def **str** of AssetLocation and AssetStatus.

I would like to access AssetLocation.location and AssetStatus.status.

I have tried to modify the form choices to this but it generates a 'Asset' object has no attribute 'location.location' error

```
REPORT_FIELDS = [('id','ID'),
                     ('name','Name'),
                     ('location.location','Location'),
                     ('status.status','Status'),
                     ]
```

How can I access foreign key values with the getattr() function?

thanks
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to be cleverer in your view code. You could try splitting on `'.'`:

```
for a in assets:
    data = []
    for i in cols:
        if '.' in col:
            fk, field = col.split('.')
            val = getattr(getattr(a, fk), field)
        else:
            val = getattr(a,i)
        data.append(val)
```

Of course, this will break if you have more than one level of relationship.

Comment: Thank you!  simplest solutions are the best!